# how could i have input save it as an integer then run it through a function

Tags: python

I am trying to run a function where I can have a user enter three integers run them through a function that will tell which number is largest.  I know there is a way to do it through the command line, but I want it to be done through the user I've tried:

```
num1 = (int(input("Enter 3 numbers and I'll tell you the largest!: ")))
num2 = (int(input("Enter another number: ")))
num3 = (int(input("And one more: ")))
def max_num(num1, num2, num3):
        if num1 >= num2 and num1 >= num3:
            return num1
        elif num2 >= num1 and num2 >= num3:
            return num2
        else:
            return num3
print (max_num())
```

When I run the command I enter three numbers. But I get 
    < function max_num at 0x00E4D7C0 >
as a result, but I want it to say what the largest number is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use this line to *call* the function, with its arguments:

```
print (max_num(num1, num2, num3))
```

Answer (score 1):

you printed function as object not called it.

```
function  # as object
function()  # as function call
```

Answer (score 0):

In python everything is an object. So what you have done basically is defined a function `def max_num(num1, num2, num3):` which takes 3 int arguments.

Now that is just defining a function, When you need to call that function you need to pass exactly 3 int arguments.

What you have done is `print(max_num)` which will refer to the function object created inside memory and not actually calling a function.

Try to call it with `print (max_num(num1, num2, num3))` and It will work.